# Why some events hasnt been shown in Ethereum logs

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

Currently, Im trying to decode and extract some transaction logs from Ethereum by using web3.py. Here is my code:

```
def exarctevent(List, w3, target=None):
    # for tran in List:
    infos=w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(List)
    abr=[]
    log=infos["logs"]
    for case in log:
        smart_contract=case["address"]
        abi_endpoint = f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={smart_contract}&apikey={mykey}"
        abi = json.loads(requests.get(abi_endpoint).text)
        contract=w3.eth.contract(smart_contract, abi=abi["result"])
        the_event=[print(adi) for adi in contract.abi if adi['type']=='event']
```

But today when I test my codes I found the events I decoded from a transaction are far more than they showed on Ethereum.
[image]
this one is my decode result.
[image]
transaction hx: 0x7121a17975f447900eb1e5f664eed712c6129c160f0abaad70bc564cb5a3dd0e

this is what it showed on Ethereum, only one event had been put on there.
Why? Isn't it all emitted events would be recorded as logs? Why there are so many events hadn't been shown?

And another thing I wanna ask is that what can indexed parameters do. From figure 2 you can see there are two indexed_topic, what are they used for? Do I need to input data for an indexed parameter? what is the address above name mean for?

Really appreciate it if someone could answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Your pictures show two different things. Only 1 event was emitted in this transaction - the `Transfer` event. The black picture, which you said shows the events, is in fact not showing the events for that transaction but appears to be showing the contract ABI for all events in the contract instead.

> And another thing I wanna ask is that what can indexed parameters do.

Indexed parameters means that the logs are stored in a sorted manner on the nodes. It costs slightly more gas but means that when you query for certain events at a later date it will be more efficient.